# React function Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm starting to react and I have a couple of doubts. I have a function (`addProductInventroy`) that is triggered after a click. What you are trying to do is:

1. Push in an **array** the id of a clicked product
2. Create a list with all the products in the array and call the `getProduct` to return the name and product description of a rest api, through axios.

With this the system throws me the following error:

> Error: objects are not valid as React child (found: [object promise]).
>   If you intended to represent a collection of child elements, use an
>   array instead.

The first question is **how to solve the problem** and the second is to see if **there is another way** of not having to save the list in the state.

```
addProductINventroy = async e => {

        this.state.inventory.push(e.target.value);
        this.setState(
            {inventroyhtml:this.state.inventory.map((item, key) =>
            <li key={item}>{item} 
            {this.getProduct(item).name}
            </li> )

        })

    }


getProduct = async id => {

            const product = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/products/'+id);
            return {product}


    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this logic?

Comment: I am trying to add a product in a product inventory. To do this when I click on a product I would like it to be pushed in an array and displayed on the screen. Because the array is from id's I use the getProduct function to find the name of that id

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Axios so I'm not exactly sure how to use it. I'm seeing some issues with the other function though.

`this.state.inventory.push(e.target.value);` mutates the state directly. This is a **bad** idea. You can read why here: https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/. Basically, always use `setState()` when updating the state.

Secondly, I wouldn't recommend putting React components in your state. You don't need to do this, since you already have the id values of the products in your state (as far as I can tell at least). Here's an example of how to implement your logic:

```
addProductINventroy = async e => {
    // Get your API output here, it appears that Axios already 
    // conveniently turns your response into a javascript object:
    const newProduct = await getProduct(e.target.value);

    // Add your product to the inventory state object
    this.setState(inventory: [...inventory, newProduct])
}

render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map((item, index) =>
        <li key={index}>
            {item.name}
        </li> )
    })
}
```

Note that I'm using the ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) here to concatenate the id to the existing array. This creates a **new** array, and doesn't mutate the old one.

I also implemented the `render()` method, you haven't shown the part where you're rendering things. This is an example of how to access the state object when rendering.

Note that with my implementation, the `inventory` state object contains all the products in JSON format. If you need to use the `inventory` object for IDs somewhere else, you should give it a different name.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Your code has solved the error and helped me to make a cleaner and lighter code